# Linq dynamically adding where conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a gridview which has drop down boxes in each header for filtering. Each filter is loaded with the distinct values from its column when loaded. At run time, I add "ALL" to allow the user to select all from that field. I am trying to build the linq statement dynamically to ignore the field if the drop down box is set to "ALL". Is this possible? I want to see if I can do this in one single statement. The example below only shows 2 dropdown boxes, but my actually case has up to 5.

If I choose to use if then statements, I end up with spaghetti code.

```
DropDownList drpOwners = this.grdOtherQuotes.HeaderRow.FindControl("drpOwners") as DropDownList;                     
DropDownList drpCompanyName = this.grdOtherQuotes.HeaderRow.FindControl("drpCompanyName") as DropDownList;

var filteredList = (from x in allQuotes
                          where (drpOwners.SelectedValue != ALL) ? x.SalesRepFullName == drpOwners.SelectedValue:true                                    
                                && drpCompanyName.SelectedValue != ALL ? x.CompanyName == drpCompanyName.SelectedValue: true
                          select x);
```

Comment: Have you tried linqkit? http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I'd find having this broken up to be simpler:

```
IEnumerable<Quote> filteredList = allQuotes;
// If using EF or LINQ to SQL, use: IQueryable<Quote> filteredList = allQuotes;
if (drpOwners.SelectedValue != ALL) 
   filteredList = filteredList.Where(x => x.SalesRepFullName == drpOwners.SelectedValue);
if (drpCompanyName.SelectedValue != ALL) 
   filteredList = filteredList.Where(x => x.CompanyName == drpCompanyName.SelectedValue);
// More conditions as needed
```

This really isn't any longer, and it's far simpler to follow.

---

If you really wanted to be able to write this as a "one-liner", you could make an extension method to build the query.  For example, if using Entity Framework:

```
static IQueryable<T> AddCondition(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Func<bool> predicate, Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter)
{
     if (predicate())
         return queryable.Where(filter);
     else
         return queryable;
}
```

This would then let you write this as:

```
var filteredList = allQuotes
                     .AddCondition(() => drpOwners.SelectedValue != ALL, x => x.SalesRepFullName == drpOwners.SelectedValue)
                     .AddCondition(() => drpCompanyName.SelectedValue != ALL, x.CompanyName == drpCompanyName.SelectedValue);
```

You could, of course, take this even further, and make a version that hard-wires the predicate to check a combo box against "ALL", making the predicate shorter (just the combo box).

Comment: It is based on the fact that IQueryable is returned, hence the where clauses are not executed until the data is actually needed. +1

Comment: @OmegaMan The OP wasn't clear whether "allQuotes" is `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` - however, this will actually work with EF, where the original probably will not (I don't think the conditional operators in this case, where "where true", will map through with EF)

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Your code will cause the query to execute because you're using Func<T, bool>.  It should be Expression<Func<t,bool>>

Comment: @MystereMan Yeah, fixed - I originally wrote thinking LINQ to Objects, then changed at last minute, and forgot to fixed - taken care of now.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper method that handles the All logic.  Something like:

```
private bool CompareSelectedValue(string value, string dropDownValue)
{
  if(dropDownValue == "ALL")
    return true;
  else
    return value == dropDownValue;
}
```

Then your query could be:

```
var filteredList = (from x in allQuotes
                          where (CompareSelectedValue(x.SalesRepFullName, drpOwners.SelectedValue)                                    
                                && CompareSelectedValue(x.CompanyName, drpCompanyName.SelectedValue)
                          select x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create extension method(s) which encapsulate the where logic so it looks cleaner:

```
var filteredList = allQuotes.WhereDropOwnersAreContained()
                            .WhereCompanyIsContained()
                            ...
                            ;
```