# Linq merging DataTable with dynamically added primary keys

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm stumped on this one.

I'm trying to merge two `DataTable`s into one. Preferably I would use `linq` to perform this task, but the problem is I need to add conditions for the join dynamically. The data for each table comes from two different calls to stored procedures and which calls are used can be switched. The results can therefor vary in number of columns and which primary keys are available.
The goal is to replace regular strings in the first result set with a second database that can contain unicode (but only if it contains a value for that specific combination of primary keys).

My linq query would look like this:

```
var joined = (from DataRow reg in dt1.Rows
                 join DataRow uni in dt2.Rows
                     on new { prim1 = reg.ItemArray[0], prim2 = reg.ItemArray[1] }
                     equals new { prim1 = uni.ItemArray[0], prim2 = uni.ItemArray[1] }
                 select new
                     {
                         prim1 = reg.ItemArray[0],
                         prim2 = reg.ItemArray[1],
                         value1 = reg.ItemArray[4],
                         value2 = uni.ItemArray[3] ?? reg.ItemArray[3]
                     }
                );
```

This works perfectly for what I want, but as I said I need to be able to define which columns in each table are primary keys, so this:

```
join DataRow uni in dt2.Rows
                     on new { prim1 = reg.ItemArray[0], prim2 = reg.ItemArray[1] }
                     equals new { prim1 = uni.ItemArray[0], prim2 = uni.ItemArray[1] }
```

needs to be replaced by something like creating a `DataRelation` between the tables or before performing the `linq` adding the primary keys dynamically.

**ALSO**, I need to make the select something like SQLs `*` instead of specifying each column, as I do not know the number of columns in the first result set.

I've also tried joining the tables by adding primary keys and doing a merge, but how do I then choose which column in dt2 to overwrite which one in dt1?

```
DataTable join = new DataTable("joined");
join = dt1.Copy();
join.Merge(dt2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
join.AcceptChanges();
```

I'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a very simple approach, which doesn't involve creating primary key relations or joins at all. I'm sure there are more elegant or performance effective ways of solving the problem.

Basically I've adapted the solution in [Linq dynamically adding where conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919504/linq-dynamically-adding-where-conditions), where instead of joining I dynamically add `.Where`-clauses.

That way I can loop through the rows and compare for each dynamically added primary key:

```
foreach (DataRow regRow in dt1.Rows)
{
    //Select all rows in second result set
    var uniRows = (from DataRow uniRow in dt2.Rows select uniRow);
    //Add where clauses as needed
    if (firstCondition) { uniRows = uniRows.Where(x => x["SalesChannel"] == "001"); }
    else if (secondCondition) { uniRows = uniRows.Where(x => x["Language"] == "SV"); }
    else (thirdCondition) { uniRows = uniRows.Where(x => x["ArticleNo"] == "242356"); }
    // etc...
}
```

Each row gets compared to a diminishing list of rows in the second result set.