# trying to create a search and I need to do an orelse dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I created a search screen for our log tables. I give the user the option to select, via checkboxes, which applications that they want to display. They can select more than one program if they wish, or at least that is how I want to do it.

Anyhow, I have the following query:

```
     var qry = from logs in model.Logs
                where logs.LogDateTime > dateTimePicker_Start.Value &&
                      logs.LogDateTime < dateTimePicker_End.Value
                select logs;

      Guid tokenid;
      if (Guid.TryParse(textBox_TokenId.Text, out tokenid))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.TokenId == tokenid);
      }

      if (checkBox_DisplayErrors.Checked)
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.IsException);
      }

      if (checkBox_WebPortal.Checked)
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.SourceEnum == "WebPortal");
      }

      if (checkBox_SubService.Checked)
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.SourceEnum == "SubService");
      }

      if (checkBox_TruckRouting.Checked)
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.SourceEnum == "TruckRouting");
      }

      if (checkBox_SuburbanHub.Checked)
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.SourceEnum == "SuburbanHub");
      }

      if (checkBox_DisplayWarnings.Checked)
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.IsWarning);
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_Contains.Text))
      {
        qry = qry.Where(x => x.Message.Contains(textBox_Contains.Text));
      }

      qry = qry.OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDateTime);

      var nqry = qry;
```

I need the following fields to be an orelse:

```
checkBox_SuburbanHub
checkBox_WebPortal
checkBox_TruckRouting
checkBox_SubService
```

So, if they check one or more of those, the field that is x.SourceEnum can be one of the checked items.

How do I combine those to be an orelse but still depend on whether or not they have checked them?

Comment: Possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919504/linq-dynamically-adding-where-conditions

Comment: @PhilVallone see Smeegs' reply below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them all to a list, then use `contains` to do an `orelse` (actually generates an `in` clause) like so:

```
        var SourceEnumList = new List<string>();
        if (checkBox_WebPortal.Checked)
        {
            SourceEnumList.Add("WebPortal");
        }

        if (checkBox_SubService.Checked)
        {
            SourceEnumList.Add("SubService");
        }

        if (checkBox_TruckRouting.Checked)
        {
            SourceEnumList.Add("TruckRouting");
        }

        if (checkBox_SuburbanHub.Checked)
        {
            SourceEnumList.Add("SuburbanHub");

        }
        if (SourceEnumList.Any())
        {
            qry = qry.Where(x => SourceEnumList.Contains(x.SourceEnum) );
        }
```

Comment: No problem.  If this answer helped you, please mark it as the answer to help others who may come across this question.

Comment: is this really dynamic?

Comment: Yes, it generates an `in` clause in the query.  The contents of the clause are dynamic, based off of user input (checkboxes).  If nothing is checked then the clause is never added to the query, also determined by user input.

Comment: see this solution. This seems to be "more" dynamic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919504/linq-dynamically-adding-where-conditions

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question.  The solution you are proposing is what the OP already has in his code.  The solution you provided shows two different ways of stringing together `where` clauses which is essentially doing `and`s. The OP wants to mix `and`s and `or`s.  Which you really can't string together with where clauses.  But you can dynamically build an `in` clause, which is what I provided.  Your proposed solution just provides two ways to do what OP has already done.