# LINQ Conditional Where clause including multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I'm trying to build out a LINQ statement that accounts for two different conditions in the where clause and I haven't found a solution on here specific to what I'm trying to do.

I have a list of process steps that I'm trying to query as such:

```
stepsQuery = _context.ProcessSteps
    .Where(a.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.Standard)

if (includeA)
    stepsQuery = stepsQuery.Where(u => u.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.A);

if (includeB)
    stepsQuery = stepsQuery.Where(u => u.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.B);
```

I have two variables that are passed in, includeA and includeB.  I need all of the standard steps, but also A steps if includeA is true and also B steps if includeB is true.  I'm trying to put this all into one statement if it's possible.  I've been playing with 'contains' but I can't quite get this to work.

Comment: What's the type of `u.StepType`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq dynamically adding where conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919504/linq-dynamically-adding-where-conditions)

Comment: The code you already have should be working, however.

Comment: This code is confusing. What do you want to happen if both `includeA` and `includeB` are true? Because it looks like if they are both true, then *no* items will be included. What do you want to happen if both are false? That includes *everything*.  **Say more clearly what you want the code to do, with an example**.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, the code he has now replaces it does not include.  If he was using ```stepsQuery = stepsQuery.Concat(stepsQuery.Where… ``` then it would be working as is.

Comment: I like fuglede's answer below.  Just add the test inline during the initial query.  I commented on it because I read it wrong and hope that he updates it to show the entire query with it contained but it is a working answer.

Comment: @EricLippert The OP already states what he's trying to accomplish "I need all of the standard steps, but also A steps if includeA is true and also B steps if includeB is true."

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: And if I could make heads or tails of that confusing sentence, then I wouldn't have asked for clarification. The code as written is *excluding* elements, not *including* them.  The original poster may have a completely wrong idea of what `Where` does; it *reduces* the number of elements in a sequence; it does not *increase* that number.

Comment: We generally invite people to show off their attempts, so given that they're asking in the first place, it seems fair to allow non-working code as well; they do say that they can't make they're own code work and make no claim that it does. I also found the textual explanation following the code as clear as one could wish and would hardly know how to improve on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply write `stepsQuery` as

```
_context.ProcessSteps.Where(a => a.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.Standard ||
    includeA && a.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.A ||
    includeB && a.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.B)
```

Comment: This is just what he has above.  The OP is asking that if ```includeA``` that you get ```Standard``` as well as ```A``` and also if ```includeB``` you get ```B``` as well.  So it's a concat type of query.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: That's exactly what this does. You will always get the one for which `a.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.Standard` but if, say, `includeA`, then you also get those for which `a.StepType == Constants.ProcessStepTypes.A`.

Comment: No this returns Standard or A or B not all.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: The predicate is evaluated for each element.

Comment: Ok, I see now.  Apologies... You're evaluating the steptype and not showing the whole query.  I read this as the query answered.

Comment: For clarity, since I was confused others may be also; I recommend formatting the entire query with this answer.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: Makes sense; I can see how that's easy to misread. Let me update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed.  I wasn't sure how to handle the booleans within the statement.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild: Great, you're welcome. This approach may of course grow unwieldy in case the predicates grow in complexity. In those cases you may find some use in [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx), which would also be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `Contains`:

```
stepsQuery = .AsQueryable();

var stepTypes = new List<string>();
stepTypes.Add(Constants.ProcessStepTypes.Standard);
if (includeA)
    stepTypes.Add(Constants.ProcessStepTypes.A);
if (includeB)
    stepTypes.Add(Constants.ProcessStepTypes.B);

var stepsQuery = _context.ProcessSteps.Where(u => stepTypes.Contains(u.StepType));
```